# Can't multiply decimals

Tags: cmd, decimal, bitcoin

I'm trying to make a Dogecoin to Bitcoin Converter to see if you get more bitcoin with Litecoin or Dogecoin in CMD, but it won't multiply numbers with decimals!

```
@echo off
title Dogecoin to Bitcoin
goto start

:math
set/a BTC=DOGE*DtB
set/a LTC=DOGE*DtL*LtB
goto end

:start
set/p DtB="Dogecoin to Bitcoin? :"
set/p DtL="Dogecoin to Litecoin? :"
set/p LtB="Litecoin to Bitcoin? :"
set/p DOGE="How many Dogecoin? :"
goto math

:end
echo Doge: %DOGE%
echo Bitcoin with Dogecoin: %BTC%
echo Bitcoin with Litecoin: %LTC%
pause
```

Did i do something wrong or is it just CMD?

Comment: Please do not repeat tags in titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET /A` performs integer calculations only:

> Any SET /A calculation that returns a fractional result will be rounded down to the nearest whole integer.

([source](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions))

---

*Why don't you just use a spreadsheet?*